# Issues while connecting to jupyter notebook running on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to use jupyter notebook running on my ec2 instance 
I followed the steps from here : 
[steps for running notebook on ec2](https://medium.com/@josemarcialportilla/getting-spark-python-and-jupyter-notebook-running-on-amazon-ec2-dec599e1c297)

I have notebook enabled on All IPS through config file. 
Here is a picture of running notebook server

[image: notebook]

I could not figure out why I am not able to connect here are contents of my config file :

```
c = get_config()

# Notebook config this is where you saved your pem cert
c.NotebookApp.certfile = u'/home/ubuntu/certs/mycert.pem' 
# Run on all IP addresses of your instance
c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
# Don't open browser by default
c.NotebookApp.open_browser = False  
# Fix port to 8888
c.NotebookApp.port = 8888
```

When I try to access it from my local browser like this :

```
https://ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8888
```

I am not able to connect .

Comment: Solved. After modifying security groups by allowing all traffic for my IP I was able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to go to security groups and locate the VPC your ec2 is using and all All traffic for MY IP in inbound rule.